# 'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'DataSource'

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf

I am having trouble trying to get the selected value from the `ComboBox` to display in my `DataGrid`. First of all, I am using the reference of Systems.Windows.Forms. After watching a tutorial, it seems that `.DataSource` wont work.

```
private void CustomerID_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (customerCombo.Text == "CUS_ID")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = xmsql04.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com,6302 ;Initial Catalog=DAD_TruckRental_RGM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=DDQ4_Melveena;Password=fBit$73939");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT RentalId,TruckId,CustomerID,TotalPrice FROM Truckrental where CustomerID like'"+CustomerID.Text+"%'", con);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        sda.Fill(dt);
        customerDataGrid.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

It would show this error:

> 'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'DataSource' and no extension method 'DataSource' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)  ProjectDAD  C:\Users\Little
>   Grace\Desktop\ProjectDAD\RentalManagement\displayInfo.xaml.cs 73  Active

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WPF, it is [`ItemsSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource?view=netframework-4.7.2), and also in WPF you need to use [`DefaultView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.defaultview?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
customerDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```